# vb.net -- winforms -- datagridview -- new row with data filled into some cells -- disappears

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell

When I add a new row to a datagridview, I am able to add data to a cell, but when I go to the row with the mouse the data disappears out of the cell. What code is needed to get the data to stay?

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click

    ' When a new row is entered add Site id.
    Dim rRow As Integer = 0
    rRow = dgvEstimator2.NewRowIndex

    '' Set Job Site ID
    If IsDBNull(Me.dgvEstimator2(1, rRow).Value) Or IsNothing(Me.dgvEstimator2(1,       rRow).Value) Then
        Me.dgvEstimator2(1, rRow).Value = rJobsiteID
        ' .Rows(DGVRow).Cells(1).Value = objSheet.Cells(excelRow, 1).value  
        Me.dgvEstimator2.Rows(rRow).Cells(1).Value = rJobsiteID
        ' Me.dgvEstimator2.Rows(rRow).Cells(1).Selected = True
        'dataGridView1.Rows[Rowindex].Selected = true
        Me.dgvEstimator2.Rows(rRow).Selected = True
        ' dgvEstimator2.Rows(rRow).SetValues()
        dgvEstimator2.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)

    End If
```

end sub

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but it sounds like you want to set some default values for the new row?

You shouldn't need to use a button to do this - the new row should show at the bottom of your grid when you have `AllowUsersToAddRows` set true. There is an event raised when a new row needs default values and there you can populate the cells are you like.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded

    Dim index As Integer
    index = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex + 1

    e.Row.Cells("Column1").Value = index.ToString()

End Sub
```

The cells will still be editable - you can change them to be readonly if you want, which could be a good idea for id columns.